# Visual C++ 2012: Unable to start program (deletes the program on debug attempt??)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

When I try to debug my program, I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to start program 'c:\stuff\TestStuff\Debug\TestStuff.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have the correct project set as the active project, and it is an .exe that has ran fine until now.  If I only compile, it does in fact create TestStuff.exe in the proper directory, but if I try to *debug* it will delete TestStuff.exe and claim it doesn't exist!  If I delete everything in the Debug directory without changing the source, it claims everything is up to date and doesn't need to compile.  If I fiddle with my source files and recompile, the .exe appears but of course VC++ deletes it when I try to debug.

How can I escape this?

I tried renaming the .suo file to no avail, and there doesn't appear to be any other file to fiddle with besides the .sln itself...  Restarting VC++ also doesn't help :(

edit: The Release build runs from the IDE but not the Debug build.  That's like the exact opposite of useful

edit 2: if I manually run the debug TestStuff.exe I get this error:

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\stuff\TestStuff\Debug\TestStuff.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

So I guess something is terribly wrong with my program now, not sure what or why it can compile but not run.  Also, it deletes itself :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by moving `#include <CImg.h>` from a header file to a .cpp file "closer" to where the CImg calls were done.  I have no idea why, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today.
To fix it, I stop my anti-virus (Avast): it seems thats it considers my program as a suspicious exe.